# search command in emacs without wrapping around

Tags: emacs

How can I search in Emacs *without* wrapping around the beginning of the file?
And how can I search with regular expression e.g. i want to search 'service*start' (* is something)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Emacs search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) will go to the end of the file and then display this message: "Failing I-search: foo". You then have the *choice* of wrapping if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> again.

The shortcut for a regex search is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. So, to search for the pattern you specified, you would hit that key combination, and then type:

```
service.*start
```

You can also access the regex search function through the emacs menus if you are using an emacs GUI or, by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then typing

```
search-forward-regexp
```

and hitting enter.

For more information on the emacs regex format, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Search.html).